# How to remove TuneUp Utilities 2012 completely?

Tags: uninstall

I'm having an issue with TuneUP Utilities 2012. When I try to uninstall it from *add/remove programs*, the following window appears

[image: dialogue]

If I click *yes*, nothing happens. The window doesn't disappear.

If I click *no*, the window disappears.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling it first, maybe an update was released since that addressed this issue?

Comment: updated to newest version, no success

Comment: @DanielBeck - Did you really ask a user to verify they had the lastest version of scareware?

Comment: @Ramhound you mean LATEST version of SHAREWARE?:))

Comment: @TuralTeyyubogluAliyev - I consider applications like this to be a boderline virus.  I mean exactly what I said SCAREWARE, the information and how its presented, is attempting to scare you out of getting rid of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just let it sit for a while, I hit uninstall, and then continued researching the issue, and when I came back to it after a minute or two, it started the uninstall process.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, just let it sit for a while and it should begin to uninstall. It takes a while to start after clicking that button ("yes").

Comment: This answer really should be a comment to Michael's answer.